# EXTJS 5.1 TreeGrid / TreeStore appendChild

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, store

I have a tree grid displaying groups and their children (there isn't nested groups inside groups, just plain children).

One column of the tree grid is a widget column. I saw in the documentation that the 'widget' property of a widget column could be a Ext.Widget or any Ext.component.

As I needed to display two buttons and one combobox in the column, I specified the widget of the widget column to be like this:

```
widget: {                
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'column',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
    },{
        xtype: 'combo',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'id'
    },{
        xtype: 'button'
    }]
}
```

This works just fine. Now I use some custom filters by applying them on the treeStore of the treeGrid.
But sometimes (and I can't manage to know when exactly), I have this error in the console, and I can't open any groups anymore :

The console error (in yellow the calls to my custom filter methods on the tree store) :

[image]

The extjs code that caused the error:

[image]

Do you have any guess what this error could be, or by what it could be caused?
I don't have any guess about what could cause this as I am to new with extjs :/ !

Thanks a lot in advance !